# What would be the consequences of time not being "relative"

Tags: general-relativity, time

So far nobody proved Einstein wrong about Theory of relativity and time
but I'm curious:

What would be the consequences or problems if someone would prove him  wrong when it comes to relativity of time?

What if time is linear/constant?

**EDIT:**

It might be a dumb question (forgive me if its so) but could something else be relative (other then  time)?

Comment: Here's a slightly different way to think about it: Relativity is a consequence of there being a maximum speed at which information can travel from one location to another. In our universe, that maximum speed is the speed of light in a vacuum, _c_. If you make _c_ infinite it's easy to see how time becomes fixed, since every location in such a universe can instantly "see" clocks at every other location. There's no relativity of time in such a universe! However, the moment you make _c_ finite, it turns out you _cannot_ create a self-consistent universe without some form of time-space ambiguity.

Comment: @Terry Bollinger - That's a good approach, but I'd note that time could still be relative if signals could travel backwards in time as well as instantaneously, then there might still be no "preferred" definition of simultaneity (i.e. a relativistic universe with [tachyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon)).

Comment: Likewise, I suppose one could have a universe where simultaneity was *not* relative, but there was still an upper speed limit--imagine a universe where Maxwell's laws hold in a preferred frame F, but systems that aren't purely electromagnetic don't display length contraction and time dilation in the same way relativity predicts, so any observer can determine their velocity relative to F and use a Galilei transform to relate their coordinates to those of F. If no object could move faster than c relative to F, no observer would observe anything faster than 2c.

Answer (score 1):

We've already observed time dilation, so we know time isn't linear/constant. See the [Experimental confirmation section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Experimental_confirmation) of the Wikipedia page on [time dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation).

Comment: I don't think that he is doubting relativity, just wanting to grasp how and why would time not be relative.

Answer (score -1):

**could something else be relative (other then time)?**

The speed of light is relative. In 1905 it was easy for Einstein to assume that  the speed of light (relative to the observer) is independent of the speed of the light source - the assumption was false but sounded plausible since it was a tenet of the universally accepted ether theory. However this assumption, combined with the principle of relativity, produced an obvious falsehood - that the speed of light is independent of the speed of the observer as well - and Einstein had to disfigure space and time in order to camouflage the falsehood:

http://www.aip.org/history/einstein/essay-einstein-relativity.htm 
 John Stachel: "But here he ran into the most blatant-seeming contradiction, which I mentioned earlier when first discussing the two principles. As noted then, the Maxwell-Lorentz equations imply that there exists (at least) one inertial frame in which the speed of light is a constant regardless of the motion of the light source. Einstein's version of the relativity principle (minus the ether) requires that, if this is true for one inertial frame, it must be true for all inertial frames. But this seems to be nonsense. How can it happen that the speed of light relative to an observer cannot be increased or decreased if that observer moves towards or away from a light beam? Einstein states that he wrestled with this problem over a lengthy period of time, to the point of despair."

Comment: -1 for, if no other reason, making the quote sound like it supports your post. He states in the next paragraph it was only thought by Einstein to be a contradiction when assuming Galilean relativity ("he had been assuming that the ordinary Newtonian law of addition of velocities was unproblematic")

Comment: The quote does not support my post - it just describes how desperately Einstein wrestled with an obviously absurd implication. When the observer starts moving towards the light source, the wavefronts start hitting him more frequently, and given the formula (frequency)=(speed of light)/(wavelength), this can only be due to the fact that the speed of the light relative to the observer has increased, in violation of Einstein's relativity.

Comment: And his struggle was before he abandoned galilean relativity. You're correct that if you assume galilean relativity you can conclude that special relativity is wrong. But it seems like you're trying to show that special relativity is inconsistent in its own right?